# problema al utilizar Configparser

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo un archivo **.py** que debe valerse de un archivo **.ini** para crear una conexión postgresql. El problema es que cuando corro la función de **configparser** la terminal me da un error cómo si no reconociera **[postgresql]** cómo una sección. Dejo el código y el archivo .ini.

```
from configparser import ConfigParser

def config(filename='db_conn.ini', section="postgresql"):
    parser=ConfigParser()
    parser.read(filename)
    db={}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params =parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]]=param[1]
            
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} is not found in in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))
    print(db)
    return db
        
        

config()
```

Mensaje de la terminal: **raise Exception('Section {0} is not found in in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))
Exception: Section postgresql is not found in in the db_conn.ini file**

Archivo .ini:

```
[postgresql]
host=localhost
database=postgres
user=postgres
password=12345
```

He revisado el *filename* y todo está correcto, si alguien sabe dónde está mi error, gracias.
PS: Los datos de la conexión al servidor postgresql son correctos, lo he conprobado en caso de que el problema fuera ese.

Edit: A peticion de un compañero de la comunidad, reescribí un comando para comprobar que me diera 'filenotfounderror', lo cual ocurrió. Dejo aquí el código y la ruta de la carpeta dónde se encuentran ambos archivos

```
from configparser import ConfigParser



def config(filename="db_conn.ini", section="postgresql"):
    parser=ConfigParser()
    parser.read_file(open(filename))
    db={}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params =parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]]=param[1]
            
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} is not found in in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))
    print(db)
    return db
        
        

config()
```

La imagen con la estructura de archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El path de ambos archivos es el siguiente: D:\SPB(4-4-23)\Laboratorio Kivy

PS: también intenté poner el .ini una carpeta atrás ya que tuve complicaciones similares abriendo imágenes en python pero no funcionó.

Comment: Hola Carlos, pues lo único que te puedo decir es que vuelvas a revisar el nombre  y la ruta del archivo con respecto al directorio de trabajo (que no con respecto a la del modulo, esto es importante si el código que muestras es importado desde otro modulo).El código y el ini son correctos, `read` si no encuentra los archivos no lanza una excepción, simplemente tu intancia `parser` contendrá un dataset vacío, por lo que luego lanza la excepción al no encontrar la sección.Cambia `parser.read(filename)` por `parser.read_file(open(filename))`
y deberás ver un `FileNotFoundError` si no me equivoco

Comment: Si es así, como seguramente abras comprobado varias veces el nombre, lo mas probable es que sea la ruta la incorrecta. Si no das con la solución, edita la pregunta y comparte la estructura de archivos de tu proyecto y cual es el punto de entrada (archivo que ejecutas).

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla hermano, ya actualicé la pregunta, hice lo que me dijiste, y me aparece el FileNotFoundError a pesar de que el documente existe, por favor chécalo y ve si puedes ver que estoy haciendo mal

Comment: Hola Carlos, ¿el archivo que ejecutas cuando se produce el error es `config.py` o es otro?  La ruta con respecto a `config.py` importa poco, lo importante es el directorio de trabajo del proceso, y ese por defecto es el mismo directorio que el del modulo que sirve de punto de entrada al ejecutar el proyecto, es decir, el que ejecutas tu (o indirectamente tu IDE) a través de `python archivo.py` para ejecutar tu app.  Agrega la linea `from pathlib import Path;print(Path.cwd())` asi tal cual al incio de tu script config.py y muestra que te imprime.

Comment: Hola, @FJSevilla Hice lo que me pediste, no cambió nada, sigue dando el mismo error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'db_conn.ini'` y pare responder a tu primera pregunta, si, el archivo que ejecuto y donde se está produciendo ese error es config.py. Lo ejecuto desde la terminal de vscode

Comment: Si agregas la linea que comento antes `from pathlib import Path;print(Path.cwd())` como primera linea de tu funcion `config` la excepcion se producirá igualmente pero antes de ella te tiene que imprimir una ruta en la terminal, que es la ruta de trabajo en el momento de ejecutarla. Esa ruta que te imprime es lo que me gustaría que agregaras para ir descartando cosas.

Comment: @FJSevilla Muy bien, la terimial imprime este path: `D:\SPB(4-4-23)` Lo que es curiosos, porque el archivo `config.py` se encuentra dos carpetas más adentro

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla, al final puse el path completo: `D:\SPB(4-4-23)\Laboratorio Kivy\ini\db_conn.ini` y funcionó. Supongo que cómo es un pendrive donde están todos los archivos hay que poner el path completo. Aunque he trabajado en otras ocaciones de la misma forma y no hizo falta... Cosas de informática

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero de todo, hay que tener en cuenta que `ConfigParser().read` si no encuentra los archivos especificados no lanza una excepción, simplemente retorna una instancia que contendrá un dataset vacío. Esto hace que posteriormente lance la excepción al no encontrar la sección especificada en ese dataset (vacío).

Dicho esto, el problema es que la ruta relativa especificada al .ini no es la correcta, por lo que para empezar hay que aclarar como se resuelven las rutas relativas.

Imaginemos que tenemos una aplicación con esta estructura:

```
mi_app
├── app.py
└── resources
   ├── config.py
   └── db_conn.ini
```

### app.py

```
from resources import config

def main():
    conf = config()
    print(conf)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### config.py

```
from configparser import ConfigParser


def config(filename="db_conn.ini", section="postgresql"):
    parser = ConfigParser()
    with open(filename) as fp:
        parser.read_file(fp)

    if parser.has_section(section):
        return dict(parser.items(section))
    else:
        raise Exception(f'Section "{section}" is not found in in the "{filename}" file')
```

### db_conn.ini

```
[postgresql]
host=localhost
database=postgres
user=postgres
password=12345
```

`config.py` es igual que tu modulo solo que con algunas correcciones. El ini es el mismo que el de tu ejemplo.

---

**En Python, las rutas son relativas al directorio de trabajo actual**, que es generalmente el directorio desde el que ejecutas el programa o script principal. Que tu ruta relativa este definida en `config.py` no implica que se resuelva en base a la ruta del archivo `config.py`, se resolverá en base a la ruta del directorio de trabajo de la app.

Por ejemplo, si ejecutamos `app.py` directamente (desde el directorio `mi_app`):

```
fjsevilla@deck ~/mi_app> python app.py
```

Tenemos una bonita excepción:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fjsevilla/mi_app/app.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/fjsevilla/mi_app/app.py", line 4, in main
    conf = config.config()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/fjsevilla/mi_app/resources/config.py", line 6, in config
    with open(filename) as fp:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'db_conn.ini'
```

Si hacemos lo mismo pero ejecutando config.py (también desde `mi_app`):

```
fjsevilla@deck ~/mi_app [1]> python resources/config.py
```

mas de lo mismo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fjsevilla/mi_app/resources/config.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(config())
          ^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/fjsevilla/mi_app/resources/config.py", line 6, in config
    with open(filename) as fp:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'db_conn.ini'
```

En cambio, si nos movemos al directorio `resources`:

```
fjsevilla@deck ~/mi_app> cd resources
fjsevilla@deck ~/mi_app/resources> python ../app.py
```

nos muestra:

```
{'host': 'localhost', 'database': 'postgres', 'user': 'postgres', 'password': '12345'}
```

y lo mismo si ejecutamos `config.py`:

```
fjsevilla@deck ~/mi_app/resources> python config.py

{'host': 'localhost', 'database': 'postgres', 'user': 'postgres', 'password': '12345'}
```

En los dos primeros casos la ruta de trabajo es `/home/fjsevilla/mi_app` (la ruta desde la que llamamos al interprete y ejecutamos los scripts) por lo que se intenta acceder al archivo `/home/fjsevilla/mi_app/db_conn.ini`, que obviamente no existe.

En cambio, en los dos últimos casos la ruta de trabajo es `/home/fjsevilla/mi_app/resources/` y la ruta al archivo tras resolver la ruta relativa es `/home/fjsevilla/mi_app/resources/db_conn.ini`, que si existe.

Dado que en tu caso `pathlib.Path.cwd()` te muestra que el directorio de trabajo es `D:\SPB(4-4-23)`, para que funcionara desde ese directorio, la ruta debería ser `./Laboratorio Kivy/ini/db_conn.ini` y no `db_conn.ini`. El error se produce porque asumes que tu directorio de trabajo es `D:\SPB(4-4-23)\Laboratorio Kivy\ini\` pero en realidad tu (o tu IDE) estáis ejecutando el modulo desde `D:\SPB(4-4-23)`.

---

Usar rutas absolutas "harcodeadas" como planteas en tu respuesta es una opción, el problema de usar rutas absolutas así es que impide que tu app sea portable y se pueda ejecutar de forma adecuada en distintos dispositivos, en los que, a priori, la estructura del sistema de archivos diferirá.

Una forma común de resolver estos problemas es hacer uso del atributo `__file__` del modulo:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import pathlib

def config(filename="db_conn.ini", section="postgresql"):
    parser = ConfigParser()
    
    file_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / filename
    with open(file_path) as fp:
        parser.read_file(fp)

    if parser.has_section(section):
        return dict(parser.items(section))
    else:
        raise Exception(f'Section "{section}" is not found in in the "{filename}" file')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(config())
```

Aunque esta solución funciona y es suficiente en la gran mayoría de casos, tiene un problema, y es que falla si el paquete no es previamente extraído e integrado en un sistema de archivos, esto ocurre por ejemplo cuando se ejecuta desde un archivo zip o un wheel.

Si esto fuera un problema, y dado que el archivo .ini es en esencia un recurso (un archivo estático ligado a la app/paquete que no es un archivo de código), Python ofrece una solución muy oportuna a través de `importlib` de la stdlib, por ejemplo:

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import importlib.resources

def config(filename="db_conn.ini", section="postgresql"):
    parser = ConfigParser()
    res = importlib.resources.files(__package__).joinpath(filename)
    with importlib.resources.as_file(res) as path:
        with open(path) as fp:
            parser.read_file(fp)

    if parser.has_section(section):
        return dict(parser.items(section))
    else:
        raise Exception(f'Section "{section}" is not found in in the "{filename}" file')
```

Esta solución es mucho mas robusta, eso si, hay que tener en cuenta que funciona conjuntamente con el paquete y el sistema de imports, por ejemplo, funcionara perfectamente si se ejecuta `app.py` (que importa `resources`) desde cualquier ruta, soportando también la ejecución desde  zip.

Comment: Hola @FJSevilla, muchas gracias por esa explicación mas extensa sobre la naturaleza del problema, ahora entiendo mucho mejor por qué pasaba lo que pasaba. Este proyecto es local de momento, pero esperamos que crezca así que va a ser bastante util tu consejo. Por último, tengo una duda referente a python que no está relacionada con código y no quiero postearla aquí, hay algún sitio al que pueda enviarte un DM para ver di puedes ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a la ayuda de @FJSevilla, lo solucioné, solo hizo falta poner el path completo hasta el archivo. Dejo abajo el código

```
from pathlib import Path
print(Path.cwd())
from configparser import ConfigParser




def config(filename="D:\SPB(4-4-23)\Laboratorio Kivy\ini\db_conn.ini", section="postgresql"):
    parser=ConfigParser()
    parser.read_file(open(filename))
    db={}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params =parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]]=param[1]
            
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} is not found in in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))
    print(db)
    return db

config()
```